# How do I plot two or more `itemFrequencyPlot`s in the same graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, market-basket-analysis

I am analyzing data from an online store. I have calculated the "itemFrequencyPlot" of all Items, and now I want to take the first 5 items that are most frequently sold and plot them within the same graph. I have tried a few things but not success :(

This is for example how I plot 2 items but in different graphs.

```
#Sales time series per Month for 85123A
data85123A <- data[data$StockCode == "85123A", ]
timeseries85123A <- split(data85123A$Month, data85123A$InvoiceNo)  # Convert data in the list
timeseries85123A <- as(timeseries85123A,"transactions") # Convert dates to transcriptions
itemFrequencyPlot(timeseries85123A,type="absolute", main="Sales time series per Month for 85123A",
                  xlab="Month", ylab="Amount of Sales")

#Sales time series per Month for 22423
data22423 <- data[data$StockCode == "22423", ]
timeseries22423 <- split(data22423$Month, data22423$InvoiceNo)  # Convert data in the list
timeseries22423 <- as(timeseries22423,"transactions") # Convert dates to transcriptions
itemFrequencyPlot(timeseries22423,type="absolute", main="Sales time series per Month for 22423",
                  xlab="Month", ylab="Amount of Sales")
```

Comment: Can you please add an example data, so I can try to tweak your code?

Comment: I got the dataset from archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352 Fyi-I treated the data a bit before analyzing. For example, to create variables like "Month" from the initial variable InvoiceDate. Thanks @Waqas

Comment: Can you please include the code you used to import the data into R? I am using gdata but it is extremely slow on my machine.

Comment: "setwd("/Users/rfanlo/Desktop/project/non-store online retail/online_retail")"
"data <- read.csv("online_retail.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"

(Sorry I am new here and I do not know how to put the code into the grey box)

Comment: I thought data is in xlsx format?

Comment: Yep, but I converted the Excel fill to csv to work with R

Comment: Is it possible for you to send that file to me?

Comment: Sure. How could I contact you?

Comment: I thought you will send the csv file

Comment: sure, just one sec!